# Reduce space between mini frame and frame title

Tags: beamer, mini-frames, beamer-metropolis

I am using Modern (Metropolis) Theme, and the mini frame outer theme. I got the mini frames correctly; however, I would like to have less space between the mini frames and the frame title (a bit closer), i.e., the dots of the mini frame and the frame title are closer. Therefore, I can have more for the slide.

**My Code:**

```
\documentclass[10pt,aspectratio=169, compress]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frame title, numbering=fraction, titleformat title= 
smallcaps]{metropolis}      % Use metropolis theme
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=mDarkTeal}
\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{series=\bfseries}


\begin{document}
\section{Section I}
\subsection*{Section I}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\end{frame}


\section{Section II}
\subsection*{Section II}
\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
Something 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `frametitle` is inside a `beamercolorbox`, the height and depth of such a box can be controlled by `ht=...` and `dp=...`. For example one could add `ht=2.25ex` and `dp=1.1ex` (just a guess, adjust to your needs) to the definition of the frametitle:

```
\documentclass[10pt,aspectratio=169, compress]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frame title, numbering=fraction, titleformat title= 
smallcaps]{metropolis}      % Use metropolis theme
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=mDarkTeal}
\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{series=\bfseries}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[%
      wd=\paperwidth,%
      sep=0pt,%
      leftskip=\metropolis@frametitle@padding,%
      rightskip=\metropolis@frametitle@padding,%
      ht=2.25ex,%%%%%% NEW !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
      dp=1.1ex, %%%%%% NEW !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    ]{frametitle}%
  \metropolis@frametitlestrut@start%
  \insertframetitle%
  \nolinebreak%
  \metropolis@frametitlestrut@end%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Section I}
\subsection{Section I}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\end{frame}


\section{Section II}
\subsection*{Section II}
\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
Something 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @MaximilianoRodriguez You're welcome!